# Как изменить цвет фона консоли через C#?

Tags: c#, консоль

Подскажите пожалуйста как изменить цвет фона консоли через C#.
Мне нужно изменить фон консоли, а не цвет фона шрифта.

Comment: Вы хоть пытались искать ответ? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.backgroundcolor?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй Console.BackgroundColor(который по умолчанию Black).
Сразу после этого вызвать Console.Clear().

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Clear();
```